# Google Cast - Subtitles with the Styled Media Receiver?

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm using the Styled Media Receiver. I have a URL with WebVTT subtitles for my video, and I want to give them to the receiver to display them, but can't find any way to do this in the API docs.

I'm using the Styled Media Receiver because my Javascript/HTML is weak, but I haven't found a way to send it subtitles from an Android sender without using the Media Player Library.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this sample code to do your own closed caption in receiver app if you don't need/want to use Media Player lib.

https://github.com/googlecast/CastClosedCaptioning-chrome/blob/master/closedcaptioningreceiver.html

```
window.showTracks = function() {
  console.log('showTracks activeTrackIndex='+window.activeTrackIndex+' 
  if (window.activeTrackIndex != undefined &&
      window.activeTrackIndex >= 0 &&
      window.activeTrackIndex < window.tracks.length) {
    var trackElement = document.createElement('track');
    trackElement.src = window.tracks[window.activeTrackIndex]['src'];
    console.log('showTracks trackElement.src='+trackElement.src);
    if (window.mediaElement.firstChild) {
      window.mediaElement.replaceChild(
          trackElement, window.mediaElement.firstChild);
    } else {
      window.mediaElement.appendChild(trackElement);
    }
    window.mediaElement['textTracks'][0].mode = 'showing';
  } else {
    window.mediaElement['textTracks'] = null;
    window.mediaElement.innerHTML = null;
  }
};
```

The CC web vtt file is passed as custom data by a Chrome sender but you can do it using Android sender as well.

```
    var customData = event.data['customData'];
    if (customData && customData['cc']) {
      tracks = customData['cc']['tracks'];
      window.activeTrackIndex = customData['cc']['active'];
      showTracks();
    }
```

Comment: I'm setting the customData Json object exactly like the one in the example above, but no subtitles are showing. Is that supposed to work with the Styled Media Receiver?

Comment: No, Styled Media Receivers do not currently support CC, you need to create your own receiver. When we add support for CC through our SDKm we will update the Styled receiver as well.

Comment: I saw something about this. It should already be supported. But I can't find anything about this topic @AliNaddaf do you have an idea how we should implement it right now in 2021 with the styled receiver?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own receiver, custom receiver. There is a sample app in google github which you could refer. Then you could enable it by

mediaPlayer.enableCaptions(true, 'ttml' , url);